# Where to return 403 Forbidden Status?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I'm using authorized routes to get data but since the Route is forbidden, I can't return an error.

```
[Route("getTotal")]
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public IActionResult GetTotalNumbers()
{
    var test = User.Claims;

    try
    {
        var logic = new DrainlockLogic(_appSettings);
        var ret = logic.GetTotalNumbers();
        return Ok(ret);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, e);
    }
}
```

My error is always null.

```
this.homeService.getGratingNumbers()
  .pipe(
    map(itemData => {
      return itemData.map(value => {
        // return new ListItem(value.id, value.market, value.name);
        this.pieChartLabels2.push([value.name]);
        this.pieChartData2.push(value.id);
        mybackgroundColor2.push(['#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6)])
      })
    })
  )
  .subscribe((listingItem) => {
    console.log(listingItem) // gives an array of listingItem
  },
  error => console.log("oh no: " + error));
```

It there a proper way to return a status for a forbidden role access?

Thr Problem is, i am not stepping into the Method GetTotalNumbers() if I have not the Role "Admin". Therefore i can't return my own status. So the Framework itslef is returning 403. I want to pass my own Message as an error.

Comment: The `403` is returned by the framework if you applied it correctly. You can also return it manualy by returning `return Forbiden();` - what is it exactly what you are after?

Comment: Thats right im getting a 403 by the framework. But i want to pass my own message what is not possible if i have a wrong Role.

Comment: looks like you want to provide detailed info about *why the user is denied from accessing*. Well I think it's not a good practice to do like that. Detailed info can be a security issue. A general message in this case is much better. It's like when logging-in failed, we don't clearly provide a message about user not existing or password incorrect, we just return a message saying something like *not succeeded*. This is also hard to implement, the current authorization pipeline takes in many *AuthorizationHandlers* to authorize and I believe no specific reason is provided in the result.

Comment: looks like the reason it's unauthorized can be extracted from the list of failed requirements which are contained in `AuthorizationFailure.FailedRequirements` (when using authorization middleware). However, as I said, you should be careful about giving more detailed info to the client.

Comment: I think that's the solution. Thank you.

Comment: @DennisS. it's just an idea, not a solution yet. But I've just added an answer realizing that idea. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I commented under your question. You should be careful about the detailed message sent to the client. In this case, providing the required roles is not very risky.
What you have for the reason of denying the user's access are contained in the `AuthorizationFailure.FailedRequirements`. Here I introduce to you how to extract that because the default `DefaultAuthorizationService` (of `IAuthorizationService`) does not pass that down to the pipeline. The detailed pipeline starts from `AuthorizeFilter` (which may be converted from `AuthorizeAttribute`):

> [AuthorizeFilter.OnAuthorizationAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Authorization/AuthorizeFilter.cs#L196) -> [IPolicyEvaluator.AuthorizeAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Security/Authorization/Policy/src/PolicyEvaluator.cs#L87) -> [IAuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/DefaultAuthorizationService.cs#L98)

So you can see that the result from `IAuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync` is converted from `AuthorizationResult` to `PolicyAuthorizationResult` which contains much less info (of course losing all the `Failure` detail). Finally the `PolicyAuthorizationResult` is converted to just either `ForbidResutl` or `ChallengeResult`.

The idea to solve this problem is by creating your custom `IAuthorizationService` by inheriting from `DefaultAuthorizationService` and intercept the calls to `AuthorizeAsync` to capture the result into a shared in-memory, such as via the `HttpContext.Features`. Note that you can take some advantage of DI Interceptors which are available by third-party DI framework like `autofac`. Here we use the built-in DI framework so this is the best solution to help intercept the calls.

Once you have `AuthorizationResult` available after authorization, you can extract the `Failure` and convert to some friendly message (be careful to not expose sensitive info) to send to the client.

Here's the code:

```
public class HttpAppAuthorizationService : DefaultAuthorizationService, IAuthorizationService
{
    readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public HttpAppAuthorizationService(IAuthorizationPolicyProvider policyProvider, 
        IAuthorizationHandlerProvider handlers, 
        ILogger<DefaultAuthorizationService> logger, 
        IAuthorizationHandlerContextFactory contextFactory, 
        IAuthorizationEvaluator evaluator, 
        IOptions<AuthorizationOptions> options,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(policyProvider, handlers, logger, contextFactory, evaluator, options)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    async Task<AuthorizationResult> IAuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, object resource, IEnumerable<IAuthorizationRequirement> requirements)
    {
        var result = await base.AuthorizeAsync(user, resource, requirements);
        //capture the result for later using
        _setAuthorizationResultFeature(result);
        return result;
    }
    async Task<AuthorizationResult> IAuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, object resource, string policyName)
    {
        var result = await base.AuthorizeAsync(user, resource, policyName);
        //capture the result for later using
        _setAuthorizationResultFeature(result);
        return result;
    }
    void _setAuthorizationResultFeature(AuthorizationResult result)
    {
        var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        if(httpContext != null)
        {
            httpContext.Features.Set<IAuthorizationResultFeature>(new AuthorizationResultFeature(result));
        }
    }
}

public interface IAuthorizationResultFeature
{
    AuthorizationResult AuthorizationResult { get; }
}
public class AuthorizationResultFeature : IAuthorizationResultFeature
{
    public AuthorizationResultFeature(AuthorizationResult result)
    {
        AuthorizationResult = result;
    }
    public AuthorizationResult AuthorizationResult { get; }
}
```

Register your custom `IAuthorizationService` in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationService, HttpAppAuthorizationService>();
```

Now in a filter of `IAsyncAlwaysRunResultFilter`, you can extract the `IAuthorizationResultFeature` to get the detailed failure and convert it to the result you want:

```
public class CustomAsyncAlwaysRunResultFilterAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncAlwaysRunResultFilter
{
    public async Task OnResultExecutionAsync(ResultExecutingContext context, ResultExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var msg = "";
        var authorizationResult = context.HttpContext.Features.Get<IAuthorizationResultFeature>()?.AuthorizationResult;
        if(authorizationResult?.Failure != null ) {
            var rolesRequirements = authorizationResult.Failure.FailedRequirements.OfType<RolesAuthorizationRequirement>();
            msg = $@"You need to have all following roles (each group requires at least one role): 
                     {string.Join(", ", rolesRequirements.Select(e => $"({string.Join(", ", e.AllowedRoles)})"))}";
            //sends back a plain text result containing the msg
            //this can be obtained by the client
            context.Result = new ContentResult { Content = msg, StatusCode = 403 };
        }            
        await next();            
    }
}
```

Actually you can take other kinds of `AuthorizationRequirement` into the process of formatting the message as well. The code above is just an example to format only the `RolesAuthorizationRequirement` (which suits your specific case here).

The `IAsyncAlwaysRunResultFilter` should be registered globally (in the way just like other kinds of filter). I hope you know how to do that (googling will surely provide you a quick result).

Comment: This helped me solve an issue where the [Authorize(Roles = "Admin')] did not work at the controller, but it did work one level deeper when the authentication service was called with the same attribute on a method. The issue was that the role claims were not loaded and attached to the SecurityTokenDescriptor.Subject.Claims when the jwt token was created at login.

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code and trace all steps. Make sure the code throws error.

Probably, the code does not throw error.

Are you sure this is throwing error?

```
var logic = new DrainlockLogic(_appSettings);
var ret = logic.GetTotalNumbers();  
return Ok(ret);
```

I guess the method GetTolalNumbers returns null instead of throwing error.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. If i dont have the Role "Admin" i cant return anything because im not stepping into the Method itself. I get a 403 from the Framework but i want to pass my own message